# uploading multiple files using jquery file upload plugin with one request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have 6 form fields, 4 of which are file input fields that take one file each. I want to send all those files along in one post request using the jquery fileupload plugin but it only sends one file
Here's my code:

```
 $('form').fileupload({
    singleFileUploads: false,
    add: function(e, data){
      console.log(data);

        filelist.push(data.files[0])

    },
    progress: function(e, data){
      var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
      console.log(progress);
    }

  });

  participateButton=$("input[type=submit]");

  participateButton.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("filelist");
    console.log(filelist);
    $('form').fileupload('send',{files:filelist});

    });
```

I am using rails 5